# Cassandra secondary index using collection type

Tags: cassandra, cql3

Here is a cassandra table:

```
CREATE TABLE Account(
id uuid,
userRef uuid,
name map<text, text>,
dataStatus text,
dataVisibility text,
...
PRIMARY KEY( id, dataStatus, dataVisibility, userRef)
)
CREATE INDEX idx_xxx_account_name ON Account (name);
```

'name' is a cql3 column of (collection) type 'map'. My question is: is it possible to create secondary index on a map type, i.e., name?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As of Cassandra 1.2.6, custom indexes on collections are supported.

https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=cassandra.git;a=blob_plain;f=CHANGES.txt;hb=refs/tags/cassandra-1.2.6

Comment: That's *custom* indexes, meaning, you get to write some seriously low-level code and hand Cassandra a jar with your implementation.  2i on collections out of the box isn't supported until 2.1: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-4511

Comment: Yes, we discovered this. In the end we abandoned Cassandra in favour of ElasticSearch.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is quite old. In cassandra 2.1 valid syntax is

`CREATE INDEX on Account(keys(name));`

Answer (score 0):

No response? I have decided to rewrite the table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE Account(
id uuid,
userRef uuid,
**main_name text,**
**other_name map<text, text>,**
dataStatus text,
dataVisibility text,
...
PRIMARY KEY( id, dataStatus, dataVisibility, userRef)
)
CREATE INDEX idx_xxx_account_name ON Account (main_name);
```

*_name could be anything e.g., email, phone etc. For example, a main_name could be the mandatory, whereas other_name could be optional.

Anyway now I can index main_name  as a 'text' type instead of the map of text values.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your initial question:

> There is no support for secondary indexes on collections yet. Concretely, you could associate a set of tags to a user, but you cannot automatically index users by their tags yet. Adding that support is definitively on the roadmap but remains to be implemented.
>   [Coming in 1.2: Collections support in CQL3](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/cql3_collections)

Also, I don't quite see why you use a map? Why not a simple set or list? Have a look at the reference provided below.

Answer (score 0):

```
create index idx_name on Account(ENTRIES(name))
```

this is for access the rows with particular entry in map.